# Can't reliably select HDMI audio output profile

Tags: audio, nvidia, pulseaudio, hdmi, pipewire

I've connected 3 displays directly to my Nvidia GPU: my monitor, my TV and my AV receiver. Directly because my old AVR can't go beyond 1080p so I want the audio to go to my AVR and the image to my 4k TV.

Problem is, the audio output I need to select is never the same. Sometimes I need to set the output to HDMI-0 (the actual port where my AVR is connected) and other times I have to switch the profile to HDMI-1 to have the audio come through my AVR.

How is this possible? What's going on? Anyone know how to deal with this? Workarounds? Like playing audio on all outputs, regardless of selection? Is there a bug here?

I'm running Fedora 36 with Pipewire 0.3.65

I've tried this:

```bash
if ( pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_08_00.1 output:hdmi-surround ); then
    pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_08_00.1.hdmi-surround
    echo "Automatically selected hdmi-surround";
elif ( pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_08_00.1 output:hdmi-surround-extra1 ); then
    pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_08_00.1.hdmi-surround-extra1
    echo "Automatically selected hdmi-surround-extra1";
elif ( pactl set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_08_00.1 output:hdmi-surround-extra1.2 ); then
    pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_08_00.1.hdmi-surround-extra1.2
    echo "Automatically selected hdmi-surround-extra1.2";
fi
```

But the problem is that the right choice might be "hdmi-surround" while my monitor is still enabled, and when it's off, it's suddenly "hdmi-surround-extra1" but the other profile still exists. So I still end up with no sound, because it needs to be "-extra1" for some reason.